# gitlab-runner not using local image

Tags: docker, gitlab

How do I force `gitlab-runner exec docker` to use a local image?

```
Using Docker executor with image docker_compose:0.0.1 ...
Using docker image sha256:be4b46f2adbc8534c7f6738279ebedd6106969695f5e596079e89e815d375d9c for predefined container...
Pulling docker image docker_compose:0.0.1 ...
ERROR: Job failed: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for docker_compose, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
FATAL: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for docker_compose, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--docker-pull-policy never`:

```
gitlab-runner exec docker --docker-pull-policy never
```

It will not try to download any image, relying only on the local cache, which includes images you have either pulled or built yourself.

Comment: How does this fix the problem that had been posed?

Comment: It will not try to download any image, relying only on the local cache.

Comment: Adding that explanation to the body of your answer will improve it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I used `if-not-present` to be able to pull images from other repositories as well as using the local cache